# how to change axis color in google chart api?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using below URL to show line chart but one thing I have to change axis color default(black) to some other color.

http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?cht=lc&chs=250x250&chco=0000ff&chls=4,1,0&chxt=x,y&chxl=0:|0|20|40|50|60|80|100|1:|0|181.8|363.6|545.4|727.2|909&chd=t:0.0,20.0,40.0,50.0,60.000004,80.0,100.0&chf=bg,s,FFFFFF00&chm=o,0000FF,0,-1,10.0

Please figure out this one..

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [imagecharteditor](http://imagecharteditor.appspot.com/) link, where you will find **Axis style** from there you can change axis default color to some others color.